# Search for window title?

Tags: windows, window-manager, window-management

I wish a method (i.e. a window manager or an addon), **which allows me to search for a window by title inside a list of opened windows,** to switch to that window directly, instead of desperately seeking for that particular window in the taskbar.

Maybe, there is also **a command for window switching?** (switch to a window with a title that matches the given pattern).

I am sure there must be a window list command, although I have not researched one yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Window List command (wmctrl):**

```
$ wmctrl -lx
0x0540043e  0 google-chrome.Google-chrome  ubunzeus Search for window title? - Ask Ubuntu - Google Chrome
0x050000ec  0 Mail.Thunderbird      ubunzeus Inbox - Mozilla Thunderbird
0x04e1068d  0 gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal  ubunzeus ljames@ubunzeus: ~
```

**Command to switch to specific window (xdotool)**

```
$ xdotool windowactivate 0x0540043e
```

The above command will switch to the Windows with the ID **0x0540043e**, which is specific from the list for this Askubuntu message entry.

They are both in the repository:

```
$ sudo apt install wmctrl xdotool
```

**The command argument for wmtrl above is:**

- **-l** List the windows
- **-x** Include the WM_CLASSS of the window.

**The command argument for the xdotool is:**

- **windowactivate** Bring to front the window specificed
- **Window ID** The specificed window to be acted upon.